# Как закинуть одну фоновую заливку поверх другой адаптивно

Tags: html

В css прописано так:

```
@import"reset.css";
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}
content {
}
```

Я хочу сделать так чтобы див `content` был адаптивным, а так же с белым фоном и размеры его не должны превышать `widht:1220px,height:2160px` (ну или в зависимости от размера экрана).

Вопрос как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Вы это имели ввиду?

```css
html,body {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
   background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.content {
  background:#fff;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  max-width:1220px;
  max-height:2160px
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
content
</div>
```